# NDSolve problem in Mathematica 10.1, possible bug

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

The following code,

```
equation = f'[x] == ((-1 + f[x]^2) (8 f[x] + (3 (-((26 x)/9) + 4/3 Sqrt[2]
                    Sinh[(4 Sqrt[2] x)/3]))/(-((13 x^2)/9) + 
                    Cosh[(4 Sqrt[2] x)/3])))/(6 f[x]);

x0 = -0.102908399964675677353185711480594117165136825368982276944`25.

NDSolve[{equation, f[x0] == 1/10^6}, f[x], {x, x0, 0}, 
        WorkingPrecision -> 25, MaxSteps -> 100000]
```

when evaluated in Mathematica 10.0 gives the correct solution, looking like this:
[image: this]

Notice the infinite derivative at the point x0, which however it was able to solve.

Now in version 10.1 it gives the message

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At x == -0.1029083999646756771207780, step size is effectively zero; 
                singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

and is unable to leave this point, giving no solution at all.

Does anyone know what's going on?
Apparently it is fixed again in 10.3, but can something be done in 10.1, say tweaking some options in `NDSolve`, to fix it there?